# Interpreting strace for characterizing delays/latencies

Tags: performance, strace

I have a daemon running on my embedded system on Linux Kernel 2.6.27.45. One of the processes is not performing as it is supposed to and I tried to use *strace* for further analysis.( I added some functionality to print stack trace of attached process to strace, following some posts on the net).
The command used was:

```
enter code here
strace  -T -i -r -tt -q -O 1 -o /tmp/syscallsM -p $tpid
```

I get an output as follows (after sorting on column 1 ):

```
0.966638 [088cea24: 360eead8 08f9e71c ]089985d4 ]08998e20 ]12c9352c ]1058e71c ]10551388 ]1054e120 ]10517f40 ]105143e0 ]10514c1c ]write(33, "x", 1) = 1 <0.028588>

 0.417500 [088d625c: 3b3e1878 121576e8 ]12163e1c ]1216473c ]12b6e75c ]112bc3e0 ]112d7880 ]112d7aa0 ]112d6b00 ]112d9aec ]112fd000 ]ioctl(29, 0x20004c01, 0) = 0 <0.000032>

 0.282577 [1019e878: 30766c98 1374a008 ]1374a1f0 ]10198854 ]10198b0c ]1019908c ]10195cb4 ]10195e08 ]1019611c ]1019a810 ]10191fa0 ]--- SIGVTALRM (Virtual timer expired) @ 0 (0) ---

 0.252104 [082f4808: 35a55a08 0899e314 ]1217ecb8 ]11c47918 ]1219a614 ]12bfeee4 ]1058e71c ]105c51f0 ]105c5980 ]10578674 ]105bfa4c ]futex(0x89ba380, FUTEX_LOCK_PI, 1) = 0 <0.000033>
```

My questions are:

(1) If we take for eg., the line beginning with 0.252104, does it mean that 252ms includes the time taken for all the functions previously on the stack(1019e878,...10191fa0) and execution upto the point of calling futex() in the current stack (082f4808...1219a614,..10578674) PLUS time during which the task got scheduled out PLUS execution of futex() call (which is 33us)?

(2) Is there a way to figure out whether the futex() call really caused the process to wait?

(3) Does the kernel schedule this task out whenever it makes a system call?

(4) In the line beginning with 0.282577, does the SIGALARM time cause the 283ms delay?
(5) In the line beginning with  0.417500, does making an ioctl() call result in the 418ms delay? (although ioctl() itself is done in 32us).
Thanks and Regards.